# How do you determine the end of the file in a stream containing multiple streams? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, stream

I would like to split an audio file into multiple segments using ffmpeg in an AWS Lambda (NodeJS) function.

Due to the limitations of (and to optimise for) the lambda environment I would like to stream the audio into ffmpeg, perform the split on the audio file in the stream and then stream the now multiple smaller files out to s3.

After doing some research I have found the AWS S3 SDK doesn't support multiple file uploads in one stream. I could resolve this by finding the end of each new segment (file in the output stream) and creating a separate upload to s3.

**Is there a way to determine the end of a file in a stream (containing multiple files)?**

(without saving it to the file system or loading it to memory).

I have searched around and I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Show your code to understand better

Comment: The question isn't about fixing code it's more about the underlying streams and buffers which I have a pretty limited knowledge of.

Comment: Start from here [link](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I thought events are emitted at the end of the entire stream not during a stream as there is no saving being done. Are you hinting at reading the stream to determine the status of the file? If so do you know how the end of a file is indicated?

Comment: I assume you mean to use the segment muxer. If so, what protocol will the output be written over?

Comment: Yes using the fluent ffmpeg npm wrapper. The output to s3 will likely be a http put (not sure what happens under the hood with the put to s3 in the aws sdk), but the output from fluent ffmpeg will be a write stream or potentially a pass through stream.

Comment: The individual segments are controlled by the segment muxer and there's no higher-level awareness of the open/close of each segment. So,.as far as ffmpeg is concerned, the output is finished only when the final segment is done. What you could do is parse the log (by ffmpeg) since the segment muxer will announce when it opens each new segment for writing.

Comment: Ah that sounds like it could work! I will take a look and report back. Thank you Gyan.

Answer (score 0):

From Node.js [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close), the `close` event indicates the end of file.

```
rd.on('line', function(line) {
//reads line by line
console.log(line);
})
.on('close',() => {
 // EOF
 console.log('End of file!');
 process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: So can the close event be emitted multiple times ? For instance when a stream consists of multiple files?

Comment: No ffmpeg will take 1 file in the form of a stream and output 1 stream containing multiple files.

Comment: I don't know how `ffmpeg` works, try and let me know